# Check if 'onload' would have fired already?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a situation where I'd like to set an `onload` handler for a script element, but it is possible that the script element has already loaded before I do so.  If it's already loaded, I'd like to detect that and run my handler immediately.

What would be a reliable way of checking a script element's `onload` state after the fact?

BTW I know that IE uses `readyState` instead of an `onload` event so I don't need help for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that you reliably know this-- if you miss an event, then you've missed it. The simplest solution if you really can't know whether the script has already been loaded is to have the bottom of the script set some global flag indicating that it's been loaded; then you can check that, and set your onload handler if it's not present.